# asp.net MVC fetching data with table relations

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

I have created my Database which has:
Artist, tracks and TracksPerArtists

I can do sql queries through the entity model. For example when I make:

```
database.TRACK.ToList()
```

I get the list of track to be shown on index view for example. But my foreign keys come empty. While there is an artist and a track, and the correct row for ArtistsPerTrack, this item in my track.ToList() collection is empty.

Is there a different way to fetch those data?

I came from cakePHP framework in which you can define the Model.recursive property to declare the depth of the relations you want to fetch.

Is there anything similar here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is something similar.
If "database" is DataContext and Artist and Tracks have many to many relationship in database, you can fetch related entities using Include clause:

database.TRACK.Include("Artists").ToList()

where "Artists" is the name of property on Track entity.

Comment: now my ViewData.Model has a non-null ArtistsPerTrack field but while ArtistsPerTrack.track is fulled with the track details, ArtistsPerTrack.Artist is null :(

Comment: I'm not sure how your entities are associated, but maybe you should load ArtistsPerTrack and include Artists and Tracks: database.ArtistsPerTrack.Include("Artist").Include("Track").ToList(). Also you may call ArtistsPerTrack.ArtistReference.Load() before accessing property ArtistsPerTrack.Artist.

Comment: Your assumptions on my DB associations are correct! Nevertheless when I want to show the Track/Index page it's only natural to load the Track model, right?
So if I do db.Artist.Include("artistPerTrack").ToList() you say I should gotten both Tracks and in every track the Artist information?